# How do I reset the postgres password for PostgreSQL on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, password-recovery

I have installed PostgreSQL on my Windows machine for development. Now I haven't used it for a while, and have forgotten the password for user `postgres` (default admin user in PostgreSQL). How can I reset the password for `postgres` in PostgreSQL on Windows?

---

I followed Milen's suggestion, but got this message when trying to reload the configuration file:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data>pg_ctl reload -D .
pg_ctl: could not send reload signal (PID: 3396): Operation not permitted
```

In Windows there is a menu option "Reload Configuration" that worked better, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the 9.0 FAQ, [I lost the database password. What can I do to recover it?](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#I_lost_the_database_password._What_can_I_do_to_recover_it.3F):

> **I lost the database password. What can I do to recover it?**
>
> You can't. However, you can reset it to something else. To do this, you
>
> 1. Edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow trust authorization temporarily - go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674380/248616) for its location
> 2. Reload the config file (`pg_ctl reload`)
> 3. Connect and issue [`ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword';`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterrole.html) to set the new password (for first time users note the semi-colon)
> 4. Edit `pg_hba.conf` again and restore the previous settings
> 5. Reload the config file again

Comment: Can you explain `Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload)`? How do you do that?

Comment: Run 'pg_ctl' as windows root authentication