# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD null; now has locked me out of psql

Tags: postgresql, password-recovery, pg-hba.conf

I have installed postgresql version 9.3.14 on High Sierra via HomeBrew. Upon trying to access the server via psql, I was being prompted for a password for the user `postgres`. Using `postgres` as the password got me into the database, but I was confused, as I have never been prompted for a password for the default user before. I looked around online on how to circumvent this, and I tried the solution suggested by lalligood on [remove password requirement for user postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83164/remove-password-requirement-for-user-postgres?newreg=aa34aebf18274762924df4fb035dedff) which was to run `alter user postgres password null;`
and now I cannot access psql. Trying `postgres`, `null` or omitting a password does not get me in, and I do not know what to do.

Comment: On the question you linked, the accepted solution is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PostgreSQL [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). It should have lines like this **copied directly from the docs**.

```
# Allow any user on the local system to connect to any database with
# any database user name using Unix-domain sockets (the default for local
# connections).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust

# The same using local loopback TCP/IP connections.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

You don't have to keep these. But it's normal to have these so you can connect locally without having to worry about passwords using your local system authentication methods. You also don't need both of these. If you only ever connect over sockets, feel free to nuke the one with tcp. This will allow you to log in with any locally authenticated user.

So you can log in as PostgreSQL with,

```
sudo -u postgresql psql -d myDatabase
```

or using tcp

```
sudo -u postgresql psql -d myDatabase -h 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I see the following in my `pg_hba.conf` file:
`# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust`

Comment: @KPekosh that's fine so you can log in if the user your authenticating with in the database is also the user you're logged in with locally. If you want to log in with the `postgres` user, simply become the `postgres` user with `sudo` that user exists in your system (or should on *nix anyway)

Comment: I tried the `sudo -u postgresql psql -d myDatabase` suggested and I get a Permission denied message. If I try `sudo su - postgres`, I'm logged in as postgres, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: @KPekosh just try running `psql -d myDatabase` if you have `trust` it shouldn't ask you for a password. If it does did you just add that line or uncomment it? If so you need to restart the server. If not, are you connecting to the right instance. Do you have two on your machine? Is the connection not working or the login?